# scala laziness - how to get rid of return statement in this palindrome search?

Tags: scala

context: find the longest palindrome in a large body of text.

here are two solutions - one with a 'return' (breaking all the way out of nested functions), and one crappy "pure" answer. how do i write a pure solution with performance of the first?

```
  def isPalindrome(str: String) : Boolean = str.reverse == str

  def longestPalindrome(haystack : String) : String = {
    (haystack.length to 1 by -1).foreach{ substrSize =>
      haystack.sliding(substrSize).foreach{ substr =>
        if(isPalindrome(substr))
          return substr
      }
    }
    ""
  }

  def longestPalindrome2(haystack : String) : String = {
    val x = for {
      substrSize <- haystack.length to 1 by -1
      substr <- haystack.sliding(substrSize)
    } yield (substr -> isPalindrome(substr))
    x.find(_._2 == true).map(_._1).getOrElse("")
  }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like your question is how to "short-circuit" the calculation without using `return`. One way would be to create a non-strict `view` of the `Range`. Here's an example,

```
def palindromeStream(haystack : String) = {
  for {
    substrSize <- (haystack.length to 1 by -1).view
    substr <- haystack.sliding(substrSize)
    if isPalindrome(substr)
  } yield substr
}

val x = palindromeStream("a canal") // Palindromes not yet computed
x.headOption                        // Compute the first one: Some(ana)
x.toSet                             // Compute the rest: Set(n, ana, a, " ", l, c)
```

You might also consider `Range.toStream`.

Answer (score 0):

You could improve the performance of your second approach a bit:

```
def longestPalindrome3(haystack: String): String =
    (for {
      substrSize <- haystack.length to 1 by -1
      substr <- haystack.sliding(substrSize)
      if (isPalindrome(substr))
    } yield substr).headOption.getOrElse("")
```